# Connection with adb was interrupted, and attempts to reconnect have failed

Tags: android

My computer become slow because of running different application then i delete some process from window task manager. Unfortunately in this time adb.exe is also delete. I try **restart the eclipse and reconnect the my mobile to usb port** but doesnot work properly.Only remaining the restart  my computer, so how to fix this problem.

```
 [2011-10-12 15:09:00 - Ultimate Jokes] ------------------------------
 [2011-10-12 15:09:00 - Ultimate Jokes] Android Launch!
 [2011-10-12 15:09:00 - Ultimate Jokes] Connection with adb was interrupted, and attempts to reconnect have failed.
 [2011-10-12 15:09:00 - Ultimate Jokes] 5 attempts have been made to restart adb.
 [2011-10-12 15:09:00 - Ultimate Jokes] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection with adb was interrupted You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386457/connection-with-adb-was-interrupted-you-may-want-to-manually-restart-adb-from-th)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another trick is to disable and then reenable USB debugging on you phone. While doing that pulling out the usb cable and putting it back in also helps.

Answer (score 4):

Happens quite often. It's annoying buggy.

I normally go into `Task Manager` and end the process `adb.exe`. Try to run the app again and it normally says it's reconnecting. After a short time (normally by the 12th attempt) it'll kick into life.

Comment: when i run my app then every time same message display  in console nothing to increase attempt.

Answer (score 3):

I found this problem easy solution: if you are using phone.

Go to:

> setting->Application->Development->USB debugging(if unchecked this
>   checked or if checked then unchecked again checked)

Which is work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to cmd prompt

And type "**adb start-server**"

Cheears

Answer (score 2):

If you're a windows user, start a command prompt (console) and type : adb start-server. Then restart Eclipse.

**Actually just closing Eclipse and restarting it works for me. If it doesn t start messing with the adb command in the console**

Comment: i done this, but following message comes adb is out of date. but second time nothing to display but application could not run.

Answer (score 2):

Check in your android sdk-> platform-tools -> adb. if there is exist then double click of that and restart eclipse

Comment: I complete this job, but 0 attempts have been made to reconnect message output, when run the application.

Comment: @PrAndroid Same here but out of curiosity, is logcat expected to work because it works fine! The only problem is that it fails to launch my application Connection with adb was interrupted. 0 attempts have been made to reconnect. You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view. I have tried everything above! (Even switched back to java 6)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it doing the following steps:

1) Disconnect your phone from the computer

2) On command line type: adb kill-server.

3) Reconnect your phone to the computer.

4) On Command line type: adb devices

the "adb device" will start the adb demon and represent you a list of the connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem since i upgraded my ADB plugin. I guess there is some compatibility issue with other components. go to [Help > Check for updates] update everything. This worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

i tryed to restart my computer and it did not work and i reinstalled  eclipse and it did not change but i disabled my avast antivirus and killed eclipse and adb process and i opened eclipse and it was working normal

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. You must uninstall previous versions of JRE or JDK (in my case I installed Java 7(adb not working). After I uninstalled Java 7 and installed Java 6 (adb working) ). After, restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

on windows, try:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for Emulator :**

Click **Home** button and then click the **Menu** button on the right-hand side panel and choose **System Settings**

Scrolldown for **Developer options** Uncheck or Check **USB Debugging** and **Stay Awake**. Click OK and then Relaunch the application.