# adb error in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

When I am running my android project the console shows me:

```
[2012-05-02 16:45:02 - AndroidFrontend] Connection with adb was interrupted.  
[2012-05-02 16:45:02 - AndroidFrontend] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.  
[2012-05-02 16:45:02 - AndroidFrontend] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection with adb was interrupted, and attempts to reconnect have failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737995/connection-with-adb-was-interrupted-and-attempts-to-reconnect-have-failed)

Comment: yes,i have reseted adb.But again some error occur as

Comment: [2012-05-02 16:58:49 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2012-05-02 16:58:50 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try restarting the adb in the DDMS Perspective.  Open the DDMS Perspective.  In the Devices tab there is a row of icons.  To the right of the icons there is a down arrow.  Click the down arrow and then click "Reset adb".

If that doesn't work try restarting eclipse.  If you have two instances of eclipse open that would be an issue so close one.  If you have a few emulators open that can sometimes cause issues too.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can just kill the process adb.exe via taskmanager and then restart eclipse.
This will automaticly restart the adb. Restarting eclipse maybe only won't help cause adb is still running in the background.