# Connection with adb was interrupted You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using Windows 7 and JDK 6.

I downloaded the package of Android SDK with Eclipse and followed the instructions to create the first Hello World application.

However, when I stand on MainActiviy.java and click on run I get the following error in the console:

> Connection with adb was interrupted You may want to manually restart
>   adb from the Devices view.

I tried many answers that I saw here:
1. Restart adb server
2. Make sure that the path is to the correct JDK
3. I went over preferences and didn't see any warning or error.

I can run the emulator- and it works fine. But it doesn't run the Hello World application.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to go to DDMS view, and in view menu of the devices, to choose:

restart ADB.

This made everything work fine

Comment: Or simply unplug and plug back your device... it usually works for me! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are followed list of options what you can do to try to fix that issue:

- Run: `adb kill-Server` , after `adb start-Server`
- Try to disable and after set enable USB debugging on device.
  While doing that pulling out the USB cable and putting it back in also helps.
- Just wait, sometimes it happens if it up slowly and Eclipse drop this error.
- Try to kill adb.exe through Task Manager. It will restart by different way.
- You can try to up performance to your Eclipse (mostly for Android):

  open `eclipse.ini` and set:

  ```
   -Xms128m        
   -Xmx512m         
   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`
  ```
- try to disable firewall
- Uninstall previous versions of  JRE or JDK (if you have ones in additional to new that you currently use). After, restart Eclipse
- Does DDMS see your emulator? Try to restart `adb` through DDMS
- Also add (if still you didn't) ADB to global path: My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variables -> press `New...` `name: ADB`; `value: <your android SDK path>\platform-tools`. after add to path %ADB%

Comment: I am not running the device - but the emulator

Comment: Just wait, sometimes it happens if it up slowly and Eclipse drop this error

Comment: doesn't help. I get now [2012-11-14 22:10:49 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 56

Comment: Did you try to kill adb.exe through Task Manager. It will restart by diferent way.

Comment: As suggested by @Fess, i think it should work after killing adb.exe

Comment: You can try to up performance to your Eclipse: open eclipse.ini and set -Xms128m  -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: Ok, 2 other things:  (1) try to disable firwall; (2) Did you installed new JRE or JDK before? if yes, uninstall previous versions. after Restart Eclipse

Comment: (3) thing: what is your `adb` path in windows global parameters. (4) Does ddms see your emulator

Comment: 1. Disabled 2. No - I m using 6 3. There is no path to adb in windows 4. How can I see if ddmms see the emulator?

Comment: open folder where you installed Android SDK: %PATH_ANDROID_SDK%/tools. There you have ddms.bat. Launch it. Verify that you see there  your emulator.

Comment: Also add (if still u didn't) ADB to global path: My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System settings -> Environment Variables -> press `New...` name: ADB; value: <your android SDK path>\platform-tools. after add to `path` `%ADB%`

Comment: well I found what to do - I had to click on the device menu: reset adb and everything started working

Comment: good to hear and welcome to Android world :)    For other users you welcome to answer on your qustion

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Dejel's answer above with one change:

1. Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS (DDMS could be in the "Other..." section)
2. Window -> Show View -> Devices (if not already visible on the left pane)
3. Under the view-meny (little downward-pointing triangle on "Devices" header) choose "Reset adb" (Restart may have been renamed to "reset" in newer versions).

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the similar problem. Struggled alot to resolve and finally this worked out for me.

1. Remove all the folders in the root folder of workspace(except workspace folder) like .android, .eclipse, .metadata etc
2. Save your platfoms to some safer place and delete the folder "adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729"
3. Unzip the bundle again to some other locations
4. Try running the eclipse again and create an application
5. Run the application and see whether emulator automatically gets starting
6. Paste back ur platforms

This worked for me on my 4th attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thing very simple.. I copied the adb.exe from users folder (users//android-sdks/platform-tools to tools folder under android-sdks.

Then in preferences under Android i clicked "restore Defaults" then again browsed back to C:\Users\\android-sdks then clicked on the latest API (19) clicked ok..

then it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

simply go to device manager in your laptop or pc -> go to processes -> click on adb and -> click on end process.

Now go to sdk folder (it may be locate various location in your drive) and right click on adb.exe and click run as administrator.

Now check if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me. Follow these steps :-

> 1. Close Eclipse.
> 2. Kill **adb.exe** from Task Manager (Windows Only)
> 3. Disconnect your device.
> 4. Reconnect your device.
> 5. Start Eclipse and Wait for Eclipse to build workspace.

P.S. This works perfectly on a Physical Device. I haven't tried it on Emulator.