# Problems with Android Debug Bridge

Tags: android, eclipse

I have the following problem while trying to run my newly created Android Application using Eclipse and the ADT plugin on Windows 8:

```
[2013-12-09 19:26:39 - SampleApp] ------------------------------
[2013-12-09 19:26:39 - SampleApp] Android Launch!
[2013-12-09 19:26:39 - SampleApp] Connection with adb was interrupted.
[2013-12-09 19:26:39 - SampleApp] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
[2013-12-09 19:26:39 - SampleApp] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

I've tried what it says to do and that doesn't work. I also tried searching the rest of this forum and could not find anything. As a workaround, I have to export my application as an APK and then push that to my device which is weird because it can see my device while pushing the file but has this other problem. I'm using the Nexus Root Toolkit to push the file. I also have a Nexus 4 not rooted or unlocked with USB Debugging on (yes I have tried toggling that 3 times and it still doesn't work).

Help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance, 
Andrew

Comment: I've seen this before, try some of these solutions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737995/connection-with-adb-was-interrupted-and-attempts-to-reconnect-have-failed

Comment: I found that same thread and tried those steps but none of those worked. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first.
Are you trying to run your app in AVD or on actual device?
For AVD follow the steps in given link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

The virtual device should start up.
Then you can try running your app on AVD.

For Running app on Actual device you need not root it. Just enable installation from unknown sources.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Surprised someone found this question. I figured it out and never came back to let anyone know. I'll mark it as best.